# Gibberish output when activating Miniconda environment in Git Bash

Tags: conda, git-bash, miniconda

My Git Bash terminal in Windows works fine with all other git bash commands but for activating conda using Git Bash for an environment, output is all gibberish. I've not been able to find anyone else facing this issue. To get back I have to kill and start a new terminal. It is a new installation of Miniconda and I also had this same issue in a previous installation and also on a different environment. It works fine with Native Anaconda Prompt, but I love using Git Bash for my work flow so I would appreciate a way to solve this.

```
Megh@Meghs-PC MINGW64 ~
$ cd trial/


Megh@Meghs-PC MINGW64 ~/trial
$ conda activate .\\env 
(C:\Users\Megh00:01:22rialö© 
ÍåçèÀÍåçèó­ÐÃ ÍÉÎÇ×¶´ þ¯ôòéáì
¤
```

or

```
Megh@Meghs-PC MINGW64 ~/trial
$ conda activate ./env 
(C:\Users\Megh00:01:22rialö© 
ÍåçèÀÍåçèó­ÐÃ ÍÉÎÇ×¶´ þ¯ôòéáì
¤
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is linked to `.env` or `.bashrc` content.

Following "[How to add Conda to Git Bash (Windows)](https://fmorenovr.medium.com/how-to-add-conda-to-git-bash-windows-21f5e5987f3d)" from [Felipe A. Moreno](https://github.com/fmorenovr), you can add conda to your Git bash with:

> - go to the folder: Anaconda/etc/profile.d/
> - open a new instance of Git Bash to the correct directory.
>
> Now, so long as the path to your file has no spaces, you can add `conda.sh` to your .bashrc with this simple command:
>
> ```
> echo ". ${PWD}/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
> ```

As seen in "[Setting Up Conda in Git Bash](https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/setting-up-conda-in-git-bash/534473)", you might need to use `conda`, not `conda.sh`.

Then::

> reopen Git Bash, you still won’t see (base) in your prompt — that’s because you haven’t activated conda yet.
> To activate it, simply type the command `conda activate`

So no `.env` in that case.

Comment: Not working! Any other ideas? My .bashrc file contains this . /c/Users/Megh/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh

Comment: @MeghRathod What Git version are you using? Do you see strange characters when typing `source ~/.bashrc`? And when typing directly `source /c/Users/Megh/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`

Comment: No, I'm using the latest Git Version "Git for Windows 2.32.0.windows.2 (64-bit)"